# Where to find Android app icon on expo Go?

Tags: react-native, expo-go

Where does the app icon display on expo go for react native apps because on iOS it's on the dev menu but on Android it don't display on the dev menu[image: expo go android app dev menu]. Where to find the app icon on Android expo go?